# Instantiating array of game objects can't get parent transform [Editor Scripting]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I want to instantiate an array of game objects via editor scripting. Now the problem is when I instantiate the prefab, it loses its parent in the hierarchy. When I'm instantiating like the script below, it works just fine:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){ //_dTarget.halfLength; i++){
    GameObject a = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(_dTarget.wallTile);
    a.transform.parent = goTarget.transform;
}
```

but if I'm instantiating like this:

```
GameObject[] testG = new GameObject[20];
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    testG[i] = _dTarget.wallTile;
}
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){ //_dTarget.halfLength; i++){
    GameObject a = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(testG[i]);
    a.transform.parent = goTarget.transform;
}
```

they lost their parent and instantiated outside the parent:

[image]

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: You know that you can instantiate an object and set it's parent in one call ? [Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Comment: Of course I know that ! But this thing is different. It's editor scripting.

Comment: did you try transform.SetParent method instead of assigning parent?

Comment: I already tried that and the result is same as before @UmairM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can set the parent, you need to disconnect the new object from the prefab. You do this with [PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance.html).

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    GameObject a = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(testG[i]);
    PrefabUtility.DisconnectPrefabInstance(a);
    a.transform.parent = goTarget.transform;
}
```

**Update:**
As of **Unity 2018.3**, `DisconnectPrefabInstance` is **obsolete**. [PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance.html) can be used instead.

Comment: It works ! But why I must do that ? Can you please explain it ?

Comment: When editing a connected instance, it's like editing the actual prefab. Any changes you do will get recorded (and can be listed with [PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications.html)), but will not take effect, or be saved to the prefab, before calling [PrefabUtility.SetPropertyModifications](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.SetPropertyModifications.html). So if you only want to change the instance and not the actual prefab, it must be disconnected first.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the explanation sir ! Now I know how it works. :)